# Parameterising node relationships using Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a group of servers that perform specific roles with dependencies between them i.e.

```
web server -> application server -> database server
```

I have Chef cookbooks that can build nodes with those roles. I am generating each node's hosts file using Chef and am using the [hosted Chef Server](https://manage.chef.io/). So far so good. What I can't quite get to grips with is how to flexibly represent the relationships between nodes with the different roles.

By flexibly I mean that in development I may just have one node that fulfils all three roles, whereas in the staging and production environments they'd be separated out into at least one node per role.

It's not clear to me how to parameterise the generation of the hosts files to accommodate this requirement. How are other people tackling this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a chef-server setup/hosted chef?

Chef runs a tool called `ohai` on each converge which collects all information about a node (e.g. IP addresses, interfaces, storage, package data) and writes it to the `node` object. When the converge is finished, the chef-client will upload the node object data to the chef-server where it will be stored and be available for search from all other nodes/clients:

Manual: http://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html

Depending on how you have split your stages, e.g. using different chef environments, use tags or some custom logic, you can dynamically build an `/etc/hosts` file, reconfigure load balancers and firewall rules using the search. Example: https://serverfault.com/questions/412127/chef-recipe-read-attributes-from-another-node

If you are not using a Chef-Server based setup, this will not be possible. You will have to manually "describe" your infrastructure/topology, e.g. inside a data bag or attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned - I'm using hosted Chef. Thanks.